# Bluemixで利用可能なサービスについて

Tags: bluemix

Bluemixで、Internet of Things Foundation Starterボイラープレートを利用しようと考えていますが、カタログの中に、該当のボイラープレートが見当たりません。
Web上では、サービスが提供されていることになっており、停止したということでもない様なのですが、自分のカタログには出てきませんでした。
無償利用の場合は、カタログに出てこないなどの制約があるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

このリンクを開くとどうなりますか？

https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/starters/internet-of-things-foundation-starter/

もしかすると、Bluemix のリージョンが US-South ではないのかもしれません。リージョンによって使えるカタログが少し異なります。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。確かにリージョンが異なっていたようです。
英国のリージョンでは発見できました。
大変助かりました。